# How to set callback URI with ProviderSignInController?

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth, spring-social

When i was using login with spring social using oAuthOperations this is how i used to set callback URI.

```
ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = (ConnectionFactoryRegistry) conf.connectionFactoryLocator();
    FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (FacebookConnectionFactory)registry.getConnectionFactory( "facebook");


OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
    OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
    params.setRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/Social/CallBackFB?au=yes");
    String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
    try
    {
        response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
    }
```

Above thing worked like a charm, But now i am using ProviderSignInController please tell me how to set the callback URI with this, i have tried to set it with bean properties.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        <constructor-arg ref="simpleSignInAdapter">
            <!-- <bean class="com.controllers.SimpleSignInAdapter" /> -->
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="PostSignInUrl"
            value="http://localhost:8080/Social/CallBackFB?au=yes" />
    </bean>
```

But still i get this response from Facebook

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

EDITED : Facebook Settings

```
Website with Facebook Login
Site URL: http://localhost:8080/Social/CallBackFB/

App on Facebook
Canvas Page: https://apps.facebook.com/weblikeapp

https://apps.facebook.com/weblikeapp
Canvas URL: http://localhost:8080/Social/CallBackFB/

Secure Canvas URL: https://localhost:8080/Social/CallBackFB/
```

**THIS IS NOT ACTUAL QUESTION, ACTUAL QUESTION IS TITLE OF THIS POST !**
Please tell me how to properly configure callback i am referring spring-social-quickstart-30x. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart

I figured out how to set callback in facebook, now i am seeking help with how to set URI in ProviderSigninController. Please Help !

Many Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow this callback URL in the settings of corresponding facebook application (Facebook App Page -> basic tab -> "Website with Facebook Login" option). Facebook blocks any attempt to redirect user to some URL not allowed there. Your current problem is on the Facebook side. You can't fix this problem in your Spring Social configuration.

Comment: Hello Maksym,
Thanks for replying, i have given facebook details also in the edit.
So does that mean i need a real URL for my application to test login with facebook ?
Is there any way for me to test it locally ?
Many thanks again !

Comment: Previosly I was able to use localhost for testing purposes. Try to change the value of "Website with Facebook Login" option to something like `http://localhost:8080/Social/`

Comment: Yes, @Maksym Demida , it worked like a charm, what i left blank was the APP DOMAINS : field empty, I have written there "localhost" and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks a ton Maksym !! :)

Comment: One more thing i still want to know is, we need to set the callBack URL at both the sides in application and in facebook, facebook is ok, but in application with ProviderSignInController is "setPostSignInUrl" the right place to set callback URL ?

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and then accept it (unansvered question will not confuse stack users anymore; your answer may be helpful for somebody)